# while using tween animation builder , in builder function while using parameters iam getting the error can anyone solve

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

[this image contains of code please give solution for this ,the lines which are in red color are the error in the code ,they are all due to  passing color as argument in the mode widget and taking color as parameter in the builder function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQkNd.png)

Comment: `TweenAnimationBuilder` takes a type `T`, which should be the type of the value, that you're using from your builder function.

Comment: @ASAD HAMEED ,bro iam not getting what you have said ,could you please elaborate ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.